# Parameter substitution

Tags: bash

I have a variable called `line` which holds a line from XML

```
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $line
<Ticket State="inWork" />
user@ubuntu:~$
```

I want to get the `inWork` text, so basically the string between quotes. Want to accomplish that using **${var#Pattern}** and **${var%Pattern}** [syntax](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

First part works as expected

```
user@ubuntu:~$ line=${line#*\"}
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $line
inWork" />
user@ubuntu:~$
```

But second part does not strip the `" />`

```
user@ubuntu:~$ line=${line%*\"}
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $line
inWork" />
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Any clue why that does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the pattern `*\"` doesn't match. What you want in the end-of-string scenario is `\"*`:

```
line='<Ticket State="inWork" />'
echo ${line#*\"}
echo ${line%\"*}
```

A possible alternative that doesn't use parameter substitution:

```
cut -d'"' -f2 <<< $line
```

Comment: Oh yes, have to look on it _in reverse_ when matching from the end. thanks for quick answer